# Can't get routes {MyEngine::Engine.routes} to work with shared examples using rspec-rails 3.1.0 and Rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to update an engine I wrote in rails 4.1 to rails 4.2. This introduced a deprecation warning around using :use_route in my controller specs.

I have removed every place where I am using :use_route and have replaced it with putting routes {MyEngine::Engine.routes} at the top of the controller spec. This has worked as expected for all of the tests in the controller spec except for the ones that deal with shared examples.

None of my shared examples pass and I get the following:

```
Failure/Error: action
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"foo/roles", :id=>"1"}
```

I would like to know how to get my shared examples to pass given this way of adding routes to my controller specs.

An example of one of the specs I have is:

```
spec/controllers/roles_controller_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

module Foo
  describe RolesController do
    routes {Foo::Engine.routes}
    before { sign_in_user FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true)}

    it_behaves_like 'requires admin privilege' do
      let(:action) {get :show, id: role.id}
    end
  end
end

spec/support/shared_examples.rb
  shared_examples "requires admin privilege" do
    routes { Foo::Engine.routes }
    it 'redirects to main app root if user is not an admin' do
      session[:user_id] = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      action
     expect(response).to redirect_to main_app.root_path
    end
  end
```

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Ever get this sorted out?  I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Looking at the engine that I might have been working on when I posted this. Have a look at the following gist to see how I resolved it:
[https://gist.github.com/vmcilwain/969b1c67c610f1967d25d1b44a6d2564](https://gist.github.com/vmcilwain/969b1c67c610f1967d25d1b44a6d2564)
Hope this helps